# find a general expression for the remainder when a prime divides a fibonacci.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers

I have primes of form $5k\pm1$. Consider the equation: $F_n=f(n)\pmod p$ where $F_n$ is the nth fibonacci number. Now given a c, how can i check whether or not there exists a solution for $f(n)=c \pmod p$? For what values of c can i eliminate the possibility of a solution? For every p, about half the values of c($0\leq c\leq p-1)$ cannot be obtained.

Comment: If I am not missing something obvious you can use $f(n)=F_n$.

Answer (score 0):

The primefactors of $f(n)$ occur periodically when $n$ gets increased. Primes $p$ of the form $p \equiv\pm1 \pmod 5$ have period-lengthes which are a divisor of $p-1$.  *(That of the form $p \equiv \pm 2 \pmod 5$ have period-lengthes which are a divisor of $p+1$).*

***Which*** divisor - I don't see this at the moment, perhaps there are rules similar as for the primefactors of $2^n-1$ depending on the residues $\pmod 8$.

That length of the period determines also the number of possible residues $c = F_n \pmod p$ - but not only: also there might be residues $c$ which occur twice or more times in one period - this all reduces the number of residues which can actually occur.

But I don't see any simple rule for this - so I think, there is no simpler way other than practically to enumerate one cycle of residues and check, whether they match you $c$.

Here is one table for the consecutive residues of the $F_n \pmod {31}$ For consecutive $n$ read them along one column, then the next column nd so on - we see the periodicity of length 30 immediately. There does not appear one simple scheme, ***which*** residues occur and which don't...

```
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   ...
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   ...
   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8
  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13
  21  21  21  21  21  21  21  21
   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
  24  24  24  24  24  24  24  24
  27  27  27  27  27  27  27  27
  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20
  16  16  16  16  16  16  16  16
   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
  21  21  21  21  21  21  21  21
  26  26  26  26  26  26  26  26
  16  16  16  16  16  16  16  16
  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11
  27  27  27  27  27  27  27  27
   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7
   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13
  23  23  23  23  23  23  23  23
   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
  28  28  28  28  28  28  28  28
   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

It might be a bit more instructive to see the residues of the squares, which exhibit the symmetry when the sign *modulo p* disappears:

```
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9
  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25
   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14
   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7
   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9
  18  18  18  18  18  18  18  18
  16  16  16  16  16  16  16  16
  28  28  28  28  28  28  28  28
   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8
  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25
   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7
  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25
   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8
  28  28  28  28  28  28  28  28
  16  16  16  16  16  16  16  16
  18  18  18  18  18  18  18  18
   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9
   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7
  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14
   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25
   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9
   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

The process of looking for $F_n = c \mod p$ in the fibonacci series, the heron series, and kindred pell-like systems, is that there is governed by two different versions of Gauss's law of quadratic residue.  The actual laws need to take the double quadratic residues into account.

You have to take this into account.  It really does not matter if these one looks for.

For $c$ to work in primes of the form of $5k\pm 1$, then you need to show that $c=d+d^{-1} \pmod p$.    This is because in these primes, and these primes only, there is a solution to $3=d+d^{-1}$, which is what is required of the Fibonacci series.  The Heron series requires a solution $4=d+d^{-1}$.  So, for $p=11$, you can take a number, eg $2$, and its recriprocal $6$, and $2+6=8$, which means that $8$ might work as a solution.  However, there is no requirement that the fibonacci numbers visit all of these numbers.

Note modulo 11, we might find that $5+9 = 3\pmod{11}$, which is required for any prime $p$ for which the fibonacci numbers having $p \mid F_{p_1}$.

It still does not mean that such a solution exists, but it does mean that primes of this form have a period that divides $p-1$.  This particular process works with the lucas numbers $L_{2n}$  (this series begins 2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, ...)

But there is something like half the numbers which will never be seen.

Comment: Please explain this statement: For c to work in primes of the form of 5k±1, then you need to show that c=d+d−1(modp). This is because in these primes, and these primes only, there is a solution to 3=d+d−1, which is what is required of the Fibonacci series.